# How should I format chapters in my manuscript?

Tags: formatting, editing, beta-readers, manuscripts

I'm in my final stages of editing before I send my manuscript to beta readers. I'm wondering how I should format chapter titles. Do I put them as a header, or as a slightly larger, bolder font?

(This is the first thing I am sending out to beta readers, so I have never done this before and I don't know if there is a standard that everyone follows. Just wondering)

Comment: What do the authors of the books you read do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the 2 Beta requests I have right now, the chapter headings are bolded and centered before the main body.

Honestly I could care less if the chapter heading was rainbow colored and Comic Sans, it just needs to be there and make it clear that it's a new chapter. As @Mary says, we(or at least I) aren't looking for fancy formatting and stuff like that.

Hope this helps, and Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's fine just to center them (on a new page).  The beta readers aren't looking for fancy formatting.